# did facebook oauth/authorize get deprecated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have been authenticating user against facebook using an api call like

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=715408518535970&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth%2Fecho&scope=email%2Cread_stream

this would redirect and there would be an access_token query parameter.
Now during the redirect, there is only a query parameter called code.

Has this method of authenticating been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is deprecated.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

[Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.